# How to convert datetime string "0 days 01:32:56.696000" to minutes

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I have datetime strings which are like
(a) 0 days 01:32:56.696000
(b) 2 days 05:12:55.781000
etc.

I want these values to be converted to minutes.
Is there is inbuilt method OR short code to do this?

Below is my code which is bit BIG. I'm looking for a more efficient way.

```
def index_nth_occurrence_string(original_string, find_string, nth_occurence):
    sep = original_string.split(find_string, nth_occurence)
    if len(sep) <= nth_occurence:
        return -1
    return len(original_string) - len(sep[-1]) - len(find_string)

def str_datetime_to_minute(datetime_str):
    #datetime_str format = '0 days 01:32:56.696000'
    idx_first_space = index_nth_occurrence_string(original_string=datetime_str, find_string=' ', nth_occurence=1)
    day_val = datetime_str[:idx_first_space]
    idx_second_space = index_nth_occurrence_string(original_string=val1, find_string=' ', nth_occurence=2)
    time_val = datetime_str[idx_second_space + 1:]
    hh_mm_ss = time_val.split('.')[0]
    t = hh_mm_ss.split(':')
    total_minutes = int(day_val) * 1440 + int(t[0]) * 60 + int(t[1]) * 1 + int(t[2]) / 60
    total_minutes = total_minutes.__round__(2)
    return total_minutes

val1 = '0 days 01:32:56.696000'
val2 = '2 days 05:12:55.781000'

print(f"val1 minutes = {str_datetime_to_minute(val1)}")
print(f"val2 minutes = {str_datetime_to_minute(val2)}")
```

Sample output:

```
val1 minutes = 92.93
val2 minutes = 3192.92
```

Comment: besides, you're dealing with a *duration* here, not a date/time. subtle difference there ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the time portion of the input string in a more readable manner:

```
from datetime import datetime
from operator import attrgetter

def str_datetime_to_minute(datetime_str):
    days, time = datetime_str.split(' days ')
    hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds = attrgetter(
        'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'microsecond'
    )(datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S.%f'))
    return (
        int(days) * 24 * 60 +
        hours * 60 +
        minutes +
        seconds / 60 +
        microseconds / 60 / 1000000
    )
```

so that:

```
str_datetime_to_minute('2 days 05:12:55.781000')
```

returns:

```
3192.9296833333333
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AlarmingBumpyTags

Answer (score 0):

pandas as a [parser](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) - might be overkill depending on application, but convenient nevertheless:

```py
import pandas as pd

val1 = '0 days 01:32:56.696000'
val2 = '2 days 05:12:55.781000'

print(round(pd.to_timedelta(val1).total_seconds()/60, 2))
# 92.94

print(round(pd.to_timedelta(val2).total_seconds()/60, 2))
# 3192.93
```